# Settng up svn server on linux (centos)

Tags: svn, centos, plink, svnserve

I am trying unsuccesssully to set up svn server on a centos vm.

I have followed 3 different tutorial and everytime ended up with the same result so I guess its time to ask for some help!

I have created an svn user, svn group, created a repository, this is all fine and worked every time and I get all the svn directories under /home/svn/repositories.

Now is where I am confused, I can never log into svn using tortoise plink and a username\password. It always fails to authenticate me. I have tried setting the ssh login for the svn user and the svn users password in the /conf/passwd file to the same thing and still cant get in.

Do I use the ssh login details(which work using putty) for my user account or do I use the ones I can enter into the passwd file in my repo/conf/passwd?

I should have added that I can access via the commandline using:

```
  svn co svn+ssh://svn@myhost/myproject
  Checked out revision 0.
```

This seems to be what the tutorial demonstrates as working:

http://andrewpuschak.com/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=installing_svn_on_centos

Any help to get this working would be massively appreciated.

Comment: After doing this 4 times now I have realised that I need to put my login credentials in 5 times to actually get to the repository, and every time I want to do anything. I dont know what is causing this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do 2 things to get this working:

1) Follow the tutorial I posted above, this was the last one I tried and it worked

2) In tortoise go settings >> network >> SSH - enter my ssh Client into the box with my credentials:

```
 C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoisePlink.exe  -l svnUsername -pw password
```